# Find the point that holds a given property

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I have a normal distribution with mean 106, and a standard deviation of 8. I'm being asked to find the point that has the property that 25% of these values have this value or lower.

What I've concluded on my own (I'm just learning *Mathematica*) is that the value I'm looking for would be `y` in the following:

```
NProbability[x <= y, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[106,8]] = 0.25
```

Since I'm not very well versed in the language, I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction here.

Comment: Try `FindRoot[
 CDF[NormalDistribution[106, 8], x] == 0.25,
 {x, 106}
 ]`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: Could use `Quantile` e.g. `Quantile[NormalDistribution[106, 8], .25]` which gives 100.604081998.

Comment: check out `InverseCDF[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic of your question is [equation solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/EquationSolving.html).  For numerical equation solving, look up [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) and [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html).

Your particular problem can be solved using

```
FindRoot[ CDF[NormalDistribution[106, 8], x] == 0.25, {x, 106} ]
```